# Handling connection error with Socket.IO for Swift

Tags: swift, socket.io

The `SocketIOClient` in Swift Socket.IO does not seem to emit any event in case the socket fails to connect. There is an `.error` event but it only seems to be emitted in case there's an error while using an already-connected socket.

```swift
socket.on(clientEvent: .error) {[self] data, ack in
  print("*** This code is not called")  
}
```

Is there a way to handled the "connection refused" error to, for instance, show an error to the user and reconnect on the background?

Answer (score 2):

Figured this one out.

There's a variant of `connect` with a timeout and an error handler.

```swift
  socket.connect(
      withPayload: nil,
      timeoutAfter: 5 /* seconds */,
      withHandler: {
          print("*** Failed to connect")
      }
)
```

One gotcha here is that even though the socket fails to connect immediately with `connection refused`, the `handler` will only be called after the timeout specified as the `timeoutAfter` parameter.

Comment: Can we have an error code or description inside the WithHandler?

Comment: this is insane, but unfortunately, no :/